# Adding Info.plist in a XCode project

Tags: xcode

When I create a Mac OS X project in XCode, I do not get a Info.plist as I do if I create a IOS project. I have tried just adding a Info.plist and pointing to it in the build settings, but my application does not use the Info.plist

What does it take to make my application react to settings (like CFBundleName) in the Info.plist?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's almost impossible that Xcode doesn't generate an info.plist. Are you able to compile your application? Check the resources folder. There should be a file called "YourApplication-Info.plist"

Comment: Uhm yes... I should stop working when I am to tired, thank you for reminding me.

Comment: Some 3rd-party project templates for Xcode do not include an Info.plist file, in those cases how would one add it?

Comment: No Info.plist created when using `swift package generate-xcodeproj`

Comment: Xcode 13 actually will not create a Info.plist anymore by default.