# Why can't I see my app icon on iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, info.plist

I'm trying to run my app on iOS simulator; it says its loaded and running, and I see the simulator, but don't see an icon for my app.

How do I fix this?

Some background:

- Initially, app wasn't running because of the error 'Couldn't find Info.plist file' file. So I removed this file from Build Phases -> Compile Sources
- Also, I now see 'InfoPlist.strings' in red color under >Pages.

**UPDATE**

I was able to undo the Plist file deletion, but still getting error that the file InfoPlist.strings can't be found because it doesn't exist.

I think there is something fishy in code above from .xcodeproj file below.. grateful for advice.

**RELEVANT CODE FROM PROJECT.XCODEPROJ FILE**

```
/* en */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = text.plist.strings; name = en;    path = en.lproj/Localizable.strings; sourceTree = SOURCE_ROOT; };

/* Info.plist */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = text.plist.xml; path = Info.plist; sourceTree = SOURCE_ROOT; };
```

Comment: Where do you set your icon image ?

Comment: in /projectname/ios/images/

Comment: I don't see the app name on the simulator screen either

Comment: it's because you remove info.plist file this file may content your application Icons  and Application name.now you delete this file so it couldn't load icon and Application name

Comment: You'll probably need to create a new project now (with the same name everything as the current project) and then copy that info.plist back into the original project.

Comment: i was able to add back that plist file (by checking out of my changes on git), but still getting an error... details are in update above. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you delete .info because info plist file may content info related to your application icons and application name

This file is load application name and icons now you delete this file so it not able to load application name and icon name

if you find error **"Couldn't find Info.plist file"** than refer this links

[can't find info.plist in xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456045/cant-find-info-plist-in-xcode-4)

[Adding Info.plist in a XCode project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326371/adding-info-plist-in-a-xcode-project)

these may help you some how  but don't delete info.plist

now crate new project and copy info.plist and add in you current project.
or you can recreate info.plist file by refering this link 
[How to regenerate an iPhone Xcode info.plist file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337403/how-to-regenerate-an-iphone-xcode-info-plist-file)
hope this may help you.

Comment: Hi - thanks for this. I fixed part of the problem, that is i was able to undo deletion of my plist file. Problem still exists... see edit/update above.

Comment: does info.plist file display red in your xcode project file ? if so than your xcode couldn't found it's refereance so rightclick on supporting file folder and you found option add files to "Your pojectname " add info.plist that may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your app from the simulator and cleaning your project and last rerun your app.

Comment: I don't think that this is the solution. The problem is something to do with InfoPlist.string

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your project and rebuild it, and make sure that the icon is still exist in the bundle resources via the settings.

Comment: how do i clean and rebuild it? sorry i am a newbie.

Comment: Go to the toolbar Product->Clean

Comment: this did not work - as in the clean worked, but still dont see app icon and name when i rebuild

Comment: Are u sure you have an icon!? It should be in the "Copy bundle resources" under build phases in the target